# Objective C: int suddenly changes to 1st if condition when it arrives on If/Then Statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

Ok this is a bizarre issue... rather than posting lots of code I will post a few snippets that will explain:

This is a action sheet that I have added a UIDatePicker

in my .h file

```
NSInteger tagOfDateToUse;
```

in my .m file I make sure its clear on ViewDidLoad

```
tagOfDateToUse = 0;
```

I need this variable because there are multiple text boxes on a screen that could be pulling up this action sheet. So I set this int so that if its a 100 it will go to one text box, if its a 101, it goes to another

I set the tagOfDateToUse in the IBAction. Then in the

```
(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
```

... Do some things

It works fine with the 1st one (100) but when I Hit my second button it is 101 up to this point.

As soon as it hits the if tagOfDateToUse is *_*_ it thinks it's 100 when up to this point it has been 101... what in the if statement is causing it to go back to 100... What am I missing here...

```
if (tagOfDateToUse = 100) {vacation_starton.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:selectedDate]];
    }
    else if  (tagOfDateToUse = 101)
    {
     vacation_endon.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:selectedDate]];

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: double-check your if statement...  looks like you are doing an assignment instead of a '=='.

Comment: @slycrel: You should post that as an answer as this is almost certainly the problem.

Comment: It needs to be a double equal sign..... Thanks JcPennyPincher!!!

Comment: you should accept one of the four correct answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value of 100 to tagOfDateToUse which is perfectly legal and then the value is evaluated as a boolean condition in which anything but 0 is true and only 0 is false.

Try changing it to this...

```
if (tagOfDateToUse == 100)
```

Comment: And I was beaten to the punch.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing might be the assignment you have in that conditional.  Did you mean to write `if (tagOfDateToUse == 100)` and `else if (tagOfDateToUse == 101)`?

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning 100 to tagOfDateToUse in the if statement.  You need to do a comparison instead.  It's an easy typo to make.

```
if (tagOfDateToUse = 100)
```

should be

```
if (tagOfDateToUse == 100)
```

Make sure you have the "Missing Braces and Parentheses" warning option turned on.  It really helps track these types of issues down.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (tagOfDateToUse = 100)
```

A very common mistake. Assignment is used instead of equality which is true. Change it to `==`. Some people prefer placing constant on left to avoid this.

```
if (100 == tagOfDateToUse)
```

Now if you miss one `=` then compiler will mind.

Comment: Or use a modern compiler and don't ignore the warnings.

Comment: @JeremyP, but you know, its far easier to ignore warning than to ignore a compile error. Just kidding :-). Yes you are right, nobody should ignore the warnings. They can be very dangerous and hard to figure out, just because we never think that we could make these kind of mistakes.